# CoreData query returns zero rests on subObjects initially - but after quitting all the data exists

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I'm using CoreData and I have an entity called a **FlightRecording** contained inside of this entity is a set of messages **AhrsMesages**.  I'm having strange behavior where I make a recording and then once I save the recording I load a table of past recordings which should show the number of messages per-recording.  What is happening, however, is that it shows 0 messages.  If I quit the application and restart-it and go into my recording list menu again it will correctly show the correct number of sub-entites.

I use the following code in ViewDidLoad of my **PreviousFlightVC.m** to load my flights:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"FlightRecording"];

NSSortDescriptor *originSort =
        [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"originAirport" ascending:YES];

NSSortDescriptor *destinationSort =
        [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"destinationAirport" ascending:YES];

NSSortDescriptor *dateSort =
        [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"recordingStart" ascending:YES];


fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[originSort, destinationSort, dateSort];
[fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];

self.frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

self.frc.delegate = self;
NSError *fetchingError = nil;
if ([self.frc performFetch:&fetchingError]) {
    NSLog(@"Success Fetch");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Fetch Error");
}
```

For each cell I'm generating the Count as such:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

RecordingRowCell *cell = nil;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    /* - IPAD Version */
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RecordingRowCell"];
} else {

    /* Iphone table Cells */
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"iphoneFlightCell"];
}

FlightRecording *rec = [[[self frc] fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

// Count the records
int recordCount = [rec.ahrsMessages count];
NSLog(@"%d", recordCount);

// ...
```

Does anybody have any ideas why I might be seeing this behavior?  Could I some how have left the "data" open for writing?  Any suggestions would be great.  Its a minor annoyance but I still can't exactly figure out why it is happening.

**Here is my initial table (before quitting)** - notice msgCount = 0
[image: Before Case]

**After i quit the app and restart here is my table** - notice msgCount = 6
[image: After Case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` does not track changes in related objects to the ones it is fetching (in relationships).

In your case, an addition to the `ahrsMessages` set will not be reflected in the currently fetched objects.

In any case, your count fetching in `cellForRow...` is very expensive performance wise.
It will be better to store the count in the `FlightRecording` object itself.
each time you ask for the count for an object it need to resolve the to-many relationship (a trip to the store).

Each time you add a message to a recording, increase the count of recordings in the related recording object (which will be faulted-in anyway by CoreData).
This will also cause your FRC to hear of the change and update the view.